# How can I prevent repeated malloc from slowing down system to a halt before the program is killed with SIGKILL?

Tags: arch-linux, scheduling, out-of-memory

Obviously I don't typically run:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    while (malloc(50));
    return 0;
}
```

But I have been attempting to compile large projects. When running `cmake`, my computer's resources get exhausted and it slows my computer to make it unusable for a few minutes. Then suddenly my computer is responsive again and `cmake` ends with `SIGKILL`. The solution is to run `cmake` with `-j2` to limit the amount of jobs.

However, after running my simple "memory exhauster" program shown above, I was surprised that my system overloaded in the first place. According to the man page of `malloc()`, if there is no memory available then `malloc` simply returns `0`. Why didn't my system recognize the memory problem and choose to make `malloc` fail?

In other words, I am looking for a way to configure my system so that a program cannot take all of the memory causing my system to slow to a halt. Similarly, is there a way of setting the scheduler to always give precedence to my DE?

I am running linux 5.6.6.arch1-1 x86_64 with KDE. Thanks.

Comment: Memory leaks by badly-written programs causing system crashes are a well-known problem that has been around for decades. If there was a simple solution to it, I would have thought it would have been implemented by now ..

Comment: Initially, malloc reserves space in the virtual memory system for your requests. Nothing else happens until you actually write something to it (if you use calloc, that may be immediate, or it may be smart enough to just mark the page as all-zero). Even when memory has been initialised, it can be swapped out. So your malloc has almost nothing to do with RAM space: it is not even made virtual until it is accessed, and even then any part of it may be on swap. You might look at things like soft user limits, turning off swap, etc. Your memory soak code is somewhat naive, though.

Comment: malloc(50) is also naive. Malloc will probably extend by some multiple of page size when it needs to. So malloc (50) will probably extend real memory once, then chop that into 1024 smaller pieces before it troubles the kernel again. If you want to soak memory, malloc (1024*1024) would still do several thousand hits. You could run under strace to see what really happens.

Comment: @Time4Tea If I am understanding you correctly, when running that c code it is expected that my system would slow to a halt and that there is no way preventing that (without changing the c code). Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant , I am not sure I understand your comment. It seems to me like you are saying that my code would not cause my system to slow to a halt. However, after running that code I can in fact say that it does cause my system to slow to a halt. I examined htop while running my program and I saw the mem and swp sections fill up until my system was unresponsive. I ran strace and I got lines of: 
brk(0x555a4ef8c000) = 0x555a4ef8c000
brk(0x555a4efad000) = 0x555a4efad000
brk(0x555a4efce000) = 0x555a4efce000
I am guessing that it calls mmap every once in a while, but I did not witness that.

Comment: I am not a C developer, but my understanding of C is that it is very low-level and has no automatic 'trash collection' (which some higher-level languages like Java have). Programs are expected to manage their memory usage and release memory back to the system when they are done with it. So yes, if a C program is written badly and sucks up all of the available RAM, it is expected that the sytem will freeze or crash. See the Wikipedia article on [Memory Leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: Malloc calls brk() to extend the process memory (see man brk). The increment between each hex value is 132KB. The malloc(50) writes a header before each of your blocks, rounding it up to 72. So every page of virtual is immediately marked, even if your own code does not write to it. Bigger allocations would skip a high proportion of pages. But evidently, you can see you use all RAM and swap space, and then the Linux OOM Killer cuts in before it really breaks the whole machine. Malloc IS failing: you just choose not to exit when it returns NULL, leaving your code eating all the CPU too.

Comment: The real question is why cmake is badly configured: being as -j 2 stops it being killed, why does the default configuration not set safe limits? In the absence of your malloc test, cmake is the OOM villain here.

Comment: @Time4Tea It is practically impossible to release malloc() memory back from a process to the OS: the allocations are fragmented all over the process heap. Freed space can be re-used within the same process if that is helpful (which is not frequent). I believe that is also true of GC systems. All process memory is freed on exit from a process (apart from memory shared with another process which is still running).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant When malloc returns NULL the while loop stops. Seeing as it ends in exit code 9 (SIGKILL) (okay, I should have added a return 0 to the end of the program just in case. I added that and the test was the same), I would assume that malloc is not returning 0.

Comment: You could try [`earlyoom`](https://github.com/rfjakob/earlyoom/blob/master/README.md) [packaged](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/earlyoom/) on Archlinux and see if your program is killed before bringing your system to its knees.

Comment: @finks My apologies. I read the code right first time, not so well today. I'm not that familiar with OOM, but its criteria seem to preempt the state where there really is absolutely no space.

Comment: @A.B thanks for that link. I will try that and other OOM killers

Answer (score 0):

> According to the man page of malloc(), if there is no memory available
>   then malloc simply returns 0.

It is so specified, and your code would exit in that case. But it seems to get preempted.

Linux has an OOM (Out of Memory) killer which identifies rogue processes, kills them, and logs what it did. But it tries not be premature in its executions.

Polite applications have been known to ask the system about its configuration and tailor their behaviour accordingly. Evidently, cmake is not one of them.

Comment: The problem is that the system is de facto dead even before there is no more memory available. Because "available" in this sense does not mean "unused". It means "can be freed by the kernel under terrible pain".

Comment: There are many informative articles on StackExchange and Google (Linux OOM Killer) so just one link: linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer. Your system is crippled because it gave your process its best shot to complete, sacrificing disc cache, inode cache, and swapping out everything before it decided enough is enough. It takes a lot of time and resources to shift all that, and more to get it all back. It is somewhat of an improvement over Unix, which just died on its feet in the same circumstances, and needed a reset with a large mallet. OOM is configurable if you wish to explore further.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your system is starting to swap to disk when it is running out of RAM. This slows things down since disks are a few orders of magnitude slower than RAM. At some point virtual memory is exhausted as well and Linux' Out of Memory Killer kicks in, picks a process that it believes to be the rouge one and kills it (that's the SIGKILL you're seeing). This ensures the system stays usable.

You can limit the amount of RAM available to a process to prevent this. E.g. limit the amount of memory available to CMake to 100 MB:

```
ulimit -v 100000
cmake <args>
```

Note that you can set separate limits for RAM (-m) and virtual memory (-v). Note that if no memory is available `malloc()` will return a null pointer. Well-written software should handle this sanely while other software might die with a segmentation fault when de-referencing the null pointer.