# How to make Linux automatically shut down a program when it uses too much RAM?

Tags: linux

I have to use a Pentium E5400 with 2GB of RAM to code and it's almost impossible at this point.

I mainly do web development stuff and oftentimes a tab ends up eating too much memory and thus rendering my computer useless--not even the cursor moves.

I recall that Windows prompted you to force close the program when that happens; I do know that there is `xkill` but I can't even access the terminal. Usually, I have to reboot my PC 15 times a day.

I can't upgrade because of financial issues. Is there a way to automatically kill a program when it uses too much memory so at least I won't have to reboot my PC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually Linux' [out-of-memory killer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory#Out_of_memory_management) does a good job killing a process that is consuming too much RAM. This might not be the case if you have a small amount of RAM but a relatively large swap space. In this case you might want to [manually set a limit for the maximum RAM consumption for a particular process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582525/235891) to avoid running into a situation where your computer becomes unresponsive due to heavy swapping.